# Extjs undefined method when extending through define

Tags: javascript, extjs

Can any tell me why i keep getting a method buildItems not defined in the following code ? Am i escaping something essential ?

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Viewport', { 
extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
requires: [
    'Ext.layout.container.Border'
],

layout  : 'border',
items   : [this.buildItems()],

buildItems      : function() {
    return { region:'center',xtype:'panel'}
}
});
```

The buildItems method has no reason to be a public method, i was only trying this way first. This is the way i'm doing it now:

```
(function() {
function buildItems () {
    return [
            {
                region  : 'center',
                xtype   : 'panel',
            }, {
                region  : 'west',
                xtype   : 'panel',
                width   : 225
            },{
                region  : 'south',
                xtype   : 'panel',
                height  : 50
            },{
                region  : 'north',
                xtype   : 'panel',
                height  : 50
            }
    ]   
}

return Ext.define('MyApp.view.Viewport', { 
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    requires: [
        'Ext.layout.container.Border'
    ],

    layout  : 'border',
    items   : buildItems()
});
})();
```

Is this an overstretch ?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is: At the time of execution of the line

```
items   : [this.buildItems()],
```

the scope is the Global Object, i.e. `this` evaluates to `window`.
You should not put `items` into a class anyway, since the instances may modify the `item`'s items, so the right way to do it is

```
initComponent: function () {
    this.items = this.buildItems(); // now, "this" is the current component instance
    // superclass.initComponent...
}
```

---

Edit: As an answer to the second part of the question

This has been discussed a million times, and there's nothing wrong with making that helper function private. I personally tend to keep methods public, since that increases readability of the code. Usually I use doc comments (`@private`) as a marker, and quite simply avoid calling supposedly private methods. I think this is not a big deal, since I'm mostly not building libraries or anything reusable for third-party developers.

Comment: I added another part to my question, would that be a good way to hide the buildItems aka make it private, as there is no reason it's define public

Answer (score 0):

It is because the function is defined in another function and the viewport will be accessed outside this self-executing function. So, put this buildItems() outside the self-executing function and try the same.

Comment: I removed the second part of the question to eliminate the confusion. Your answer doesn't help though.